# margin-top set by jQuery makes content jump. How can I make it smoothly animate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The `#content` div gets a `margin-top` set through jQuery. This margin is the same height as the `#masthead` div which does not have a set height because it will be changing. This all works fine. The problem is that when I reload the page, the `#content` div "jumps" down because of the margin set by jQuery. It may be difficult to see it in the fiddle, but I have managed to recreate what I'm experiencing. How would I animate the margin so `#content` moves down smoothly?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/78a55ctm/

**HTML**

```
<div id="masthead">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* { margin:0;padding:0 }

#masthead {
    background: #000;
    color: #000;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#content {
    background: pink;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var headerTop = $('#masthead').outerHeight();
$('#content').css('margin-top', headerTop);
```

Comment: If you just want to animate the `margin-top`, you could do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/78a55ctm/6/).

Comment: Btw, this one is better ----> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78a55ctm/7/). It will only animate if the new `margin-top` value is not the same. This will prevent the delay.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py That's awesome. Also, the `resize()` was a nice added touch. I was trying to figure out how to make everything adapt to a resized browser.

Comment: Yea, I forgot to mention that you were missing the resize event. Btw, adding `.stop()` before `.animate(...)` makes it [even better](http://jsfiddle.net/78a55ctm/9/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `animate()`

```
$('#content').animate({'margin-top': headerTop + 'px'}, 700, 'easeOutExpo');
```

check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/78a55ctm/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```js
var headerTop = $('#masthead').outerHeight();
$('#content').animate({ marginTop: headerTop }, 1000);
```